# GitLab Code Coverage Badge Not Showing

Tags: regex, gitlab, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I have CI setup for a GitLab repository and the job contains the following output to the STDOUT.

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 94.25% ( 291/333 )
Branches     : 62.29% ( 53/75 )
Functions    : 73.32% ( 170/196 )
Lines        : 94.68% ( 533/569 )
================================================================================
```

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for the job I have the `coverage: /^Statements\s*:\s*([^%]+)/`. As well, in the CI/CD settings for the repository I have `^Statements\s*:\s*([^%]+)` set.

Yet code coverage appears to be `Unknown` on the code coverage badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the build needs to be passing. So a Mocha exception for example of a failing test will prevent code coverage from being extracted.

Comment: can you please share your .yml file (or a part of it where you fixed it), I'm having the same issue

Comment: @YashKaranke in my case the build needed to be passing in order for the coverage to be parsed and displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set the `multiline` flag

```
coverage: /^Statements\s*:\s*([^%]+)/m
#                                   ^^^
```

Comment: Good thought. I looked into the core build runner code and found the following which leads me to believe it uses multiline already https://gitlab.com/maxraab/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/trace/stream.rb#L68