# Gitlab's coverage badge showing always unknown

Tags: gitlab, phpunit, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, badge

I'm trying to setup the coverage badge in my project written in PHP, but it always remain as `unknown`. My current settings are:

##### 1. `.gitlab-ci.yml` test job:

```yaml
php_unit:
    stage: Test
    image: $PHP_FPM_ALPINE_IMAGE
    tags:
        - docker
    except:
        - tags
    when: on_success
    <<: *backend_cache_config
    <<: *backend_before_script
    script:
        - phpdbg -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never 
    coverage: '/^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%/'
```

##### 2. Test coverage regex set in Settings > CI/CD > General Pipelines:

[image]

##### 3. Badge configuration in Settings > General > Badges

[image]

---

Even with this settings, the badge stay as `unknown`. I've tried some of the things below, but with no success:

- [GitLab Code Coverage Badge Not Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733969/gitlab-code-coverage-badge-not-showing)
- [Gitlab coverage badge always unknow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780206/gitlab-coverage-badge-always-unknow)
- [Coverage badge in gitlab is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392931/coverage-badge-in-gitlab-is-unknown)
- [Gitlab Coverage badge not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227950/gitlab-coverage-badge-not-working)

Any ideas?

Comment: Pleae add the _Job Log_ as plain text to your question that you expect to obtain the coverage information for the badge from that gives you the _unknown_ label.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab CIs [Test coverage report badge](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-report-badge) shows **unknown** when *no coverage* information was obtained.

This is certainly the error condition, e.g. you expect to have at least some different match here (good / acceptable / medium / low).

For it to work, the *job log* must contain at least one line (the last would be taken) that matches the regular expression form the job keywords `coverage` key word.

You `coverage` regular expression is:

```
/^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%/
```

This regular expression has to match the coverage percentage number (incl. zero) and the match may contain surrounding text.

The actual number for the badge is matched by `\d+(\.\d+)?` on your regular expression match.

The most detailed description about how this regular expression works can be obtained from the [`coverage` key word documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#coverage).

As you have not shared any job log that you expect your regular expression to match against not much specifically can be said.

It appears as a configuration issue to me, and it is either that the expectation is wrong that it would match against the job log output while it does not (you can easily validate this with a regular expression test tool either on your box or online at https://regex101.com/) - or - there is a match but the matched number can not be parsed by Gitlab CI (which from my own feeling is less likely).

If you have a match of a line of your job log, then verify that match as the subject against the match of another regular expression, `\d+(\.\d+)?`, as that is the one Gitlab uses to obtain the actual number.